# Prettier игнорирует некоторые объявления в конфигурации .prettierrc в корне проекта

Tags: vim, prettier, vimrc

Использую редактор vim в работе.
В корне проекта размещаю .prettierrc со своей конфигурацией.

При форматировании текста в документе, всё работает по моей конфигурации, кроме параметра `bracketSameLine: true`.
Он почему то игнорируется и в html создаются ненужные мне переносы.

Где копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.

Значение `printWidth` по умолчанию в prettier: `80`
Нужно указать в `.prettierrc` `"printWidth": 90`.

Если строка не помещается, то prettier в любом случае её перенесет, вопрос только в том, после какого кол-ва символов